# Is the constant complexity requirement of begin() too strict for std::map?

Tags: c++, containers, time-complexity, stdmap

`std::map` meets the requirements of a [container](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#def:container) ([[map.overview] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/map.overview#2)).

[container](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#def:container) requires the following:

> ```cpp
> b.begin()
> ```
>
> *Result*: `iterator`; `const_iterator` for constant `b`.
>
> *Returns*: An iterator referring to the first element in the container.
>
> ***Complexity*: Constant.**

- [[container.requirements] `begin()`](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#lib:begin,containers)

This seems impractical to me.
A `std::map` is commonly implemented as a self-balancing binary search tree, and you typically need logarithmic complexity to find the leftmost node, where iteration has to begin.

How would you implement `begin()` in constant time? Do standard library implementations actually comply with this?

Comment: I don't have msvc. In libstdc++ and libc++ they are both defined to simply return a data member.

Comment: the rebalance doesnt happen on the call to `begin`. And inserting an element is not constantant comlexity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard requires `begin()` to be constant time, and standard libraries do comply with this. The easiest way to do this is to store the leftmost node in a member.

In libstdc++ for example, see [this comment](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_tree.h#L85C1-L89C23):

```
// (1) the header cell is maintained with links not only to the root
// but also to the leftmost node of the tree, to enable constant
// time begin(), and to the rightmost node of the tree, to enable
// linear time performance when used with the generic set algorithms
// (set_union, etc.)
```